# My registration details is not saving to my firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing this registration app and this is my first try on firebase.

My email address is saved on the authentication part of firebase but after I tried connecting my app to the database, so that I can store more info, I am getting this error when I click signup:

```
Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at validatePathString (firebase.js:1)
    at t.child (firebase.js:1)
    at userServices.js:30
    at angular.js:14634
    at m.$eval (angular.js:15878)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:15689)
    at angular.js:15917
    at e (angular.js:5490)
    at angular.js:5762
```

Here is my code:

```
angular.module("registrationApp")
           .factory("signupService", ["$rootScope", "$firebaseAuth", signupService]);

function signupService($rootScope, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    var auth = $firebaseAuth();

    return {
        signup: function (user) {
            auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                user.email,
                user.password
            ).then(function (regUser) {
                var userInfo = ref.child("Users")
                    .child(regUser.uid).set({
                        date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                        regUser: regUser.uid,
                        firstname: user.firstName,
                        email: user.email

                    })//userInfo
                $rootScope.message = "Hi  " + user.firstName + " " + "Thanks for Registering";
            }).catch(function (error) {
                $rootScope.message = error.message;
            })
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Hi,  just to make sure I understood the problem, the table Users is created or is when you are having a problem?

Comment: The function createUserWithEmailAndPassword returns a promise containing UserCredentials, so to access the user uid the good path is `regUser.user.uid`

Comment: @AlexBean the user table is NOT created. When I checked my firebase database I did not see the User table. So I believe that might be where I am having problem

Comment: @diouze I used your input and this is the response I got. 
Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.owE3rTb6FNarQBCbdyFHcHc8YqD2.regUser'

I it is still not working

Comment: You're trying to set properties of a document that doesn't exist. Use `.doc` instead of `.child` to create the new doc before setting its properties. `ref.child("Users").doc(regUser.user.uid).set({`

Comment: Thanks @JosephWebber i got this response when I used your recommendation ref.child(...).doc is not a function
Regarding your comment, I thought by initiating a variable called ref below I have created a document in the firebase database  
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is too late, but i faced the same problem and my solution was to change **regUser.uid** to **regUser.user.uid**. So the renewed code is:

```
    var userInfo= ref.child('Users')
               .child(regUser.user.uid).set({
                date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                regUser: regUser.user.uid,
                firstname: user.firstname,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                email: user.email
               })//userInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is your Reference path that you are trying to save to. You need to get rid of the ref object and just do this to store it:

```
firebase.database().ref(`Users/${regUser.uid}`).set({
    date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    regUser: regUser.uid,
    firstname: user.firstName,
    email: user.email
})
```

Currently, you are trying to get a child of nothing, so you need to build a proper reference path to where you want to store it.

Comment: Thank you.
But I get this error when I try your method. 
Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Users.undefined.regUser'
Please is it possible for you to write the way it should be maybe I am doing it all wrong? Thank you